# How to properly combine login and registration form in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have this form partial:

```
.row
    .span6
        .well
            %h2 Sign in
            = simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f|
                = f.input :email, :autofocus => true, :wrapper => :bootstrap_placeholder
                = f.input :password, :wrapper => :bootstrap_placeholder
                = f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
                = f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => 'btn-primary'
            = render "devise/shared/links"



    .span6
        .well
            %h2 Sign up
            = simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => regi stration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f|
                = f.error_notification
                = display_base_errors resource
                = f.input :name, :autofocus => true
                = f.input :email, :required => true
                = f.input :password, :required => true
                = f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true
                = f.button :submit, 'Sign up', :class => 'btn-primary'
            = render "devise/shared/links"
```

and its working ok but the problem comes with validation, when i want to register a user without entering any data... shows the error message but it also higlights the username and password field of the sign in form.. is there a way of avoiding this validation mixups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resource` is the same on both forms, so it is normal if the errors display on both. To prevent that, you have to separate the resources you use. Try something like this.

```
# registrations_controller.rb
def create
  super
  @registration_resource = resource
end

# sessions_controller.rb
def create
  super
  @login_resource = resource
end

# _form.html.slim
# sign up
simple_form_for(@registration_resource || resource_name.to_s.capitalize.constantize.new, :as => resource_name, :url => regi stration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f|

# sign in
simple_form_for(@login_resource || resource_name.to_s.capitalize.constantize.new, :as => resource_name, :url => regi stration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f|
```

Comment: Thanks! i've solved it, but the errors only showed when i changed the simple_form_for tag to: simple_form_for(@login_resource || resource ...